# GMap in iframe gets off-center

Tags: javascript, iframe, dictionary, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have a Google Map (API 2) that used to work fine as a standalone page.

However, when I load the map page within an iframe (with [Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/)), the map gets off-center:
normally it's centered over Germany and in the iframe it centers on Iran, instead.

**How to make the map center correctly?**

---

*My guesses:*

The problem can result from the iframe loading time. I guess, that the script calculates window size basing on the iframe size when it's still loading. It's strange since I load the map when the document is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setupSearchForm();
  setupMap();
  setupResults();
});
```

For instance, when I refresh the already loaded iframe the center comes back to Germany.
A sample of code loading the map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess turned out to be good. The reason was iframe size calculated during its load.

The fix is easy: just to **specify the [`size`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMapOptions.size) in [`GMapOptions`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMapOptions)** - then the map will always know how big is its container.

In my case it meant changing

```
map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
```

to

```
map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), { 
  size:new GSize(970,500),
});
```